# How to use an image as a button in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: css, image, button, jquery-mobile

I went through a search about how default buttons in jQuery Mobile can be replaced by custom images, as I am implementing code to build a PhoneGap app. I found this [one useful link](http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2011/02/13/Creating-and-using-custom-icons-in-jQuery-Mobile).

I have code like this:

```
<a href="#user_info" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-iconpos="right" data-icon="myapp-custom">Custom Icon</a>
```

And the CSS is:

```
.ui-icon-myapp-settings {
  background: url("settings.png") no-repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
}
```

Still it shows a + icon and not my icon.

```
css directory -- ../css/style.css
image directory  ../css/images/settings.png
```

And I get a view like:

What's wrong with the code or Image location?

Answer (score 12):

If you need something bigger than the icon, in order to use an image, as a button, just use the following:

`<a href="venta.html" data-theme="" id="ventaOption">
        <img src="css/images/standard/shoppingcart.png" width="26" height="26">
        <br/>
        Ventas
</a>`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<a data-role="button" href="#" data-shadow="false" data-theme="none">
  <img src="images/imagefile.png" border="0"/>
</a>
```

set the "data-theme" to "none" on your button and add "data-shadow="false".

Answer (score 2):

```
<a id='btnShowSignUp' href="#" data-shadow="false" data-theme="none"
                                    onclick="ShowSignUp();">
<img src="../assets/downArrow.png" style="height: 15px;">
</a>
```

Start off with anchor tag and add the href on click call method. Then add the img tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-icon-myapp-settings {
    background: url("images/settings.png") no-repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
}
```

Try this out.

**Custom Icons**

To use custom icons, specify a data-icon value that has a unique name like myapp-email and the button plugin will generate a class by prefixing ui-icon- to the data-icon value and apply it to the button. You can then write a CSS rule that targets the ui-icon-myapp-email class to specify the icon background source. To maintain visual consistency, create a white icon 18x18 pixels saved as a PNG-8 with alpha transparency.

Comment: that doesnt seem to be quiet a solution, what if my icon or image is greater than 18*18 pixel ? mine is 67 px *20 px

Comment: nopes it is not showing any part 100% sure u can check link i have uploaded screen shot http://img7.imagebanana.com/img/jw2s2jzy/Selection_001.png

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

After looking at some of your comments I like you wanted a custom button image. Would something like this work?

- http://jsfiddle.net/DfDet/10/

I would look into a custom header or navbar, here are the docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

Original Answer Below:

You need to prepend `ui-icon-` to you data-icon attribute value, which in you example is `myapp-custom`

So your CSS class should be this:

```
.ui-icon-myapp-custom {
    background: url("settings.png") no-repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#user_info" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-iconpos="right" data-icon="myapp-custom" >
Custom Icon
</a>
```

jQM Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

> **Custom Icons** 
>   To use custom icons, specify a data-icon value that has a
>   unique name like myapp-email and the button plugin will generate a
>   class by *prefixing ui-icon- to the data-icon value* and apply it to the
>   button. You can then write a CSS rule that targets the
>   ui-icon-myapp-email class to specify the icon background source. To
>   maintain visual consistency, create a white icon 18x18 pixels saved as
>   a PNG-8 with alpha transparency.

Example: (Doesn't look nice but has the custom icon)

- http://jsfiddle.net/DfDet/2/

Comment: Works ok only if your icon is 18x18. JQM designers should have figured people would like to use their own icons...

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
 data-icon="myapp-custom"
```

to

```
 data-icon="myapp-settings"
```

if the css is ui-icon-myapp-settings